# PDO с ssl. Ошибка SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] без описания

Tags: mysql, pdo, ssl

Доброго времени года!
При попытке установить соединение с удалённым сервером через PDO с SSL вот так

```
try{
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=db.server.ru;dbname=testbase",
                      'ssluser',
                      'pass',
                      [
                          PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY  => VARS . '/certs/client-key.pem',
                          PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => VARS . '/certs/client-cert.pem',
                          PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA   => VARS . '/certs/ca.pem'
                      ]
        );
} catch(PDOException $ex){
    var_dump($ex->getMessage());
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

Получаю ошибку SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] без остального текста.
На сервере стоит mariadb.
Сертификаты генерил [так](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-setup-mariadb-ssl-and-secure-connections-from-clients/). Common name у сертификатов разные
При выполнении на сервере, на котором исполняется скрипт с ошибкой, команды в консоли

```
mysql -h db.server.ru -ussluser -p --ssl-ca=/var/www/.../var/certs/ca.pem --ssl-cert=/var/www/.../var/certs/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/var/www/.../var/certs/client-key.pem
```

подключение происходит нормально, без ошибок.
Каталог с сертификатами выглядит так

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 apache apache 4096 Mar 15 13:40 .
drwxrwxrwx 11 root   root   4096 Mar 15 13:40 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache 1679 Mar 16 18:14 ca-key.pem
-rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache 1285 Mar 16 18:14 ca.pem
-rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache 1155 Mar 16 18:14 client-cert.pem
-rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache 1675 Mar 16 18:14 client-key.pem
-rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache  985 Mar 16 18:14 client-req.pem
-rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache 1155 Mar 16 18:14 server-cert.pem
-rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache 1679 Mar 16 18:14 server-key.pem
-rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache  985 Mar 16 18:14 server-req.pem
```

Comment: `Получаю ошибку SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] без остального текста` Остальной текст - это либо `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket`, либо `Connection refused`. Раз у Вас SSL - скорее второе. Смотрите логи MySQL-сервера и системные логи станции. Можно попробовать трассировку ODBC...

Comment: @Akina А не подскажете, какие именно логи нужны у MySql? Включены log_error | /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log и general_log_file | /var/log/mariadb/mysql.log и в них ничего нет по этому подключению. На сервере стоит centos 6, в логах messages и secure тоже нет ничего по этому подключению.